# When actual removal of a packages happen, especially arch

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I have a problem with running the database I attempt to reinstall it. Since it essentially a fresh install.

I am doing removal with `pacman -R mariadb`. My assumption I can't execute any binary from it. But it still there.

My suspicion when using Linux mint it will do the same thing.

Can someone explain comprehensively when the actual removal happen?

Comment: i believe the command is actually ```Pacman -Rns MariaDB``` let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: My problem is already gone, I am asking about the underlying removal process.
Would you explain the `Rns` operation as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you run that command, all files from that package are deleted from your system. There is no process, that schedules the deletion to a later time.

As to how the removal works:

Your package manager (any package manager tbh) has a database somewhere with all packages, all installed packages and every file of all installed packages. IIRC for pacman this should be somewhere in `/var/lib/pacman`
As soon as you remove a package, your package manager goes through the list of files belonging to said package, and basically just `rm -rf /path/to/file`.

You can see what files a package contains if you run `pacman -Ql <package-name>`. While -Q is for querying, the l is for list all files owned by a given package.

Regarding your actual problem: Did you read the installation instructions for mariadb on archlinux?

> You need to initialize the MariaDB data directory prior to starting
> the service. This can be done with mariadb-install-db command, e.g.:
> `mariadb-install-db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql`

EDIT: You probably should rather do `pacman -Rcs <package-name>` when you remove packages.

> -c, --cascade
>
> > Remove all target packages, as well as all packages that depend on one or more target packages. This operation is recursive and must be
> > used with care, since it can remove many potentially needed packages.
>
> -s, --recursive
>
> > Remove each target specified including all of their dependencies, provided that (A) they are not required by other packages; and (B)
> > they were not explicitly installed by the user. This operation is
> > recursive and analogous to a backwards --sync operation, and it helps
> > keep a clean system without orphans. If you want to omit condition
> > (B), pass this option twice.

[manpage](https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html)

Comment: IIRC, stand for?

Comment: "If I remember correctly"
If this answerd your question, please consider approving it.

Comment: Not yet, I just want to vote up first. :)